# How to delete files which contain in another .txt file using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I had created one batch file.In this I have stored:
 My query's o/p into file named List.txt Its contains multiple files.
 I want to delete these files which are contains in `List.txt`.

I am writing code :

```
set file=E:\AppData\List.txt
findstr /s /p /x /m /c:"test" *.txt> %file%
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%file%) Do 
(
    echo %%A
    set name = "E:\AppData\%%A"
    del %name% 
)
pause
```

I can not access %name% value.
How can I delete these files?

My `List.txt` contains 4 files :

Data\Application 1\1.txt
Data\Application 1\4.txt
Data\Application 2\1.txt
Data\Application 2\4.txt
Data\Application 3\1.txt

**EDIT**

I made complete batch file and when i run it i get an error

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
 E:\AppData\Data>for /F "tokens=* delims=" %A in (E:\AppData\List.txt) Do
```

I share my batch script here please can anyone find my mistake please.

```
@echo off
set file=E:\AppData\List.txt

findstr /s /p /x /m /c:"test" *.txt> %file%

  :END
    echo Files are Safe not deleted.

    call "E:\batch files\linecount.bat"

    SET /P "ANSWER=Click Y to delete all Files or N to stop (Y/N)"

    for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%file%) Do 
    (
       echo %%A
       del "E:\AppData\%%A"
    )   
    echo Files are deleted successfully.
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (List.txt) do (
  del /F /Q %%a
)
pause
```

Its working.

Answer (score 0):

you need either [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) or to change your code a little bit:

```
set file=E:\AppData\List.txt
findstr /s /p /x /m /c:"test" *.txt> %file%
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%file%) Do (
    echo %%A
    del "E:\AppData\%%A"
)
pause
```

Comment: What is delayed Expression? How it will used and what's the purpose of it?

Comment: I linked to a short explanation of delayed ex_pansion_ in my answer (click onto the blue words). In the comments there, I linked to some deeper explanations.

Comment: I again get an error when i run my batch file.

The syntax of the command is incorrect.
E:\AppData\Data>        for /F "tokens=* delims=" %A in (E:\AppData\List.txt) Do

Comment: The `(` has to be on the same line as `do`. I corrected it in my answer (no idea how it happened to be on the next line `:(`). The syntax error was, because there was no command after `do`.